# Can't step through 'Just my code' when using VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a option in VSCode when debugging like the 'Just my Code' option in Visual Studio?

I want to step through my own code, not all the internal node code like next_tick.js

I've tried adding

```
"skipFiles": [
            "node_modules/**/*.js"
        ]
```

to the debug configuration, but that's not working.

Comment: Looks like that should work but you could try the alternative: "skipFiles" :  [
   "<node_internals>/**/*.js"  ] Note the magic name <node_internals> See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_just-my-code-improvements.  Or you could just try "node_modules" without the glob on the end.

Comment: That didn't really work, debug breakpoints now seem have a life of their own...  Where is the Weißwurstäquator  between stepping through my code and system libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer can be found at the Visual Studio Code site: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome

In short, you forgot to add ${workspaceFolder}:

```
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js"
  ]
```

However, as Mark noted, there is a magic string to cover all internal node modules and then the solution is:

```
  "skipFiles": [
     "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
  ]
```

added in the .vscode/launch.json file.