# Only step through project files when debugging in VSCode with Java

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

There are loads of questions asking about how to skip over `node_modules`, but I'm looking to skip over all non-project java files like `Method.class` and `InvocableHandlerMethod.class`.  These are not node modules, so the usual settings in the `launch.json` don't work.

When I'm stepping over the code while debugging it's infuriating that I have to spend the vast majority of my time in some system library...

An example question that doesn't fit my needs is: [Can't step through 'Just my code' when using VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240298/cant-step-through-just-my-code-when-using-vscode)

**Is there any way to configure debugging in VSCode and Java to only step through files that I've created in my project?**

A perfect setup would be that I *include* folders for debugging, rather than *exclude* them as other questions specify.

Comment: maybe could use step over(F10) to skip the system method

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT That's what I've been using, and it still takes me into the system classes.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: @mikeo I'm afraid not :(

Answer (score 3):

Finally there's a solution that does the job for me. I've tried adding this rule to my settings.json file and it works:

```
"java.debug.settings.stepping.skipClasses": ["$JDK", "org.junit.*", "junit.*", "java.util.*"]
```

Thanks to [jdneo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1152#issuecomment-836406638).

Answer (score 2):

Actually VS Code Java Debugger supports filter the library code during stepping. The approach is to add `stepFilters` config in launch.json.

Below is a sample to filter the common jdk library.

```
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - Main",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "client.Main",
            "projectName": "kie-client",
            "stepFilters": {
                "classNameFilters": [
                    "java.*",
                    "javax.*",
                    "com.sun.*",
                    "sun.*",
                    "sunw.*",
                    "org.omg.*"
                ],
                "skipSynthetics": false,
                "skipStaticInitializers": false,
                "skipConstructors": false
            }
        }
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me, and I've tried this in the past too.  My app is a spring web service, and when an exception is thrown (for example) and I repeatedly press F10, I eventually go into the `Method.class` file which is part of `java.lang.reflect;` package, just as before.  Nice try though!

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. It still enters those packages.